# gapi auth2 fails with cb=gapi.loaded_0:43 Uncaught [object Object] exception if user denies permission to access google account data

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I am trying to make google plus login working for my website using gapi auth2 api.

The flow is like this:

User clicks on google+ button -> pop up to choose google account appears -> permission window (user allows/denies the permission to access account) -> I call my custom auth service using access_token provided by google -> login happens.

Everything else is working fine except for when user chooses the google account and then instead of allowing he clicks on 'Deny' button on permission window. In this case, I get the below exception:

I was expecting that when user denies the permission I will get a callback to my code from gapi but instead it fails.

Here is the code I wrote to do google+ login

```
gapi.client.setApiKey(config.apiKey);
            var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            if (auth2 == undefined) {
                auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: config.clientId,
                    scope: config.scopes,
                    immediate: false
                });
            }
            auth2.then(function() {
                var options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder();
                options.setScope(config.scopes); // Set scopes
                options.setPrompt('select_account consent'); // Get authorization from the user to access profile info
                var signIn = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn(options);
                signIn.then(function() {
                    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
                        console.log("google plus api loaded.");
                        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                            'userId': 'me'
                        });
                        request.execute(function(resp) {
                            console.log(resp.displayName);
                        });
                    });
                    var authResult = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse();
                    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                        console.log("google auth success");
                        console.log(authResult.access_token);
                        var authService = new authServiceModel.authServiceResp({});
                        var formvalues = {};
                        formvalues.Method = 3;
                        formvalues.Source = 5;
                        formvalues.GoogleToken = authResult.access_token;
                        authService.fetch(formvalues);
                    } else {
                        if (authResult && authResult.error) {
                            console.error('Unable to sign in:', authResult.error);
                        }
                        console.log("google auth failed");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

Click Deny.

Please look into the code and suggest what should I do to get a proper callback when 'Deny' button is clicked.

Thanks.